# Not getting value through call back in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, callback

I am new to Ember JS and any UI framework. Facing below issue so kindly suggest.

I have a user `object` (json) having it's `group ids` (array). Using `group Ids` I need to pull the group name and details. Using below code to get the details.

Asynchronous call is going through and fetching the data but I am not getting in nameGroup variable.

```
var nameGroupName = _.filter(user.userGroups, function(group){
     return groupService.GroupDetails(group).then(function(result) {
       return result.name;
     });
});
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `async` `promises` you have to wait until you call the next iteration. Best thing is to use a `recursive` function to iterate through the array rather than using the `lodash` or `underscore` `filter` method.

Below is an example implementation.

```
function getNameGroupName = function(userGroups, index){
  groupService.GroupDetails(userGroups[index]).then(function(result) {           
       userGroups[index] = result.name;
       index = index + 1;
       if(index < userGroups.length){
          getNameGroupName(userGroups, index)
       }
  });  
}

var nameGroupName = getNameGroupName(user.userGroups, 0);
```